# SendEmailfailed.First exception SINGLE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED

Tags: email

what is limit(number of Emails per day) of sending Email with and without attachment to email field on custom object by using trigger in developer Org.
  as of my understandings it is 15 with or without which i dont know.

Answer (score 2):

250 is the limit for Mass Email below Enterprise orgs, Enterprise have 500 limit and Unlimited is having 1000.

If you are using sandbox then there will be 10 limit per day. you can use Send Email method for maximum upto 10 times.